# What is good practice in a DB schema keeping a history of a link-table?

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

Without further ado an example:

Let's consider an arbitrary example, 3 tables, one with workers, one with tasks, a link table and consider the resolution for the history 'days'

Table "workers", (PK)id

```
id | name
---+-----------
 1 | Frank
 2 | Sam
 3 | Tony
---+-----------
```

Table "tasks", (PK)id

```
id | name
---+--------------------
 1 | walking the dog
 2 | feeding the cat
 3 | charging the robot
---+--------------------
```

Table "task_assignments",
(PK)workers.id as w_id, (FK)w_id, (FK) tasks.id as t_id

```
w_id | t_id
-----+------
 1   |  2
 2   |  3
 3   |  2
-----+------
```

So for now everything seems clear, there might also be a case where the t_id is part of the (PK) just makes no sense in this example. The link table is straight forward but how do I implement a good history?

Let's say:

- I asigned w_id(1) to t_id(2) on 1970-01-01.
- On 1970-01-02 I unassigned w_id(1) from his task, leaving no entry in
  the link table.
- On 1970-01-08 I assigned w_id(1) to t_id(1) which takes longer.
- On 1970-01-15 I unassign w_id(1) again from his task, leaving no
  entry in the link table.

How do I properly implement an history of this for data consistency and easy querying?

I want to easily query:

- What task was w_id(?) doing on 1970-01-03?
- What w_id's had no task from 1970-01-01 to 1970-01-10?
- What tasks was w_id(?) doing from 1970-01-10 to 1970-01-12?
- What tasks are currently not assigned to any worker?

I could alter the link-table to also contain a datestamp as part of the (PK) and store the assignments this way and simply store a new row with t_id=null on unasignment like so?

```
 date_set   | w_id | t_id 
------------+------+------
 1970-01-01 | 1    | 2
 1970-01-02 | 2    | 3
 1970-01-01 | 3    | 2
 1970-01-02 | 1    | null
------------+------+------
```

Or do I make some sort of "history-table" but what to put there without doubling the link-table? Creating an AI-PK for the link table and store this in a row in the history table with the datestamp? And how to handle unassigned-periods?

Is there some kind of "schema design patter" for this? I simply don't know what to search for, so basically an acceptable answer would also be a link to an article covering this topic.

Comment: you either want to use a db that supports SQL:2011 Temporal , or use the history table pattern, where you copy on delete to a similar table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use table **assignments** which looks like this:

```
 date_start | date_finish | w_id | t_id 
------------+-------------+------+-----
 1970-01-01 | 1970-01-02  | 1    | 2
 1970-01-01 | 1970-01-02  | 3    | 2
 1970-01-02 | null        | 1    | 2
 1970-01-02 | null        | 1    | 3
------------+-------------+------+------
```

Add some test data with this code:

```
CREATE table workers (
 id int,
 name text,
 primary key (id)
);

CREATE table tasks (
 id int,
 name text,
 primary key (id)
);

CREATE table assignments (
 w_id int,
 t_id int,
 date_start date,
 date_finish date
);

INSERT INTO workers VALUES (1, 'worker_a'), (2, 'worker_b'), (3, 'worker_c');
INSERT INTO tasks VALUES (1, 'task_1'), (2, 'task_2'), (3, 'task_3');

INSERT INTO assignments VALUES (1, 2, '1970-01-01', '1970-01-02'), (3, 2, '1970-01-01', '1970-01-02'), (1, 2, '1970-01-03', NULL), (1, 3, '1970-01-02', NULL);
```

Now we can experiment with desired queries.

What task was w_id(1) doing on 1970-01-03?

```
SELECT t_id FROM assignments WHERE w_id = 1 AND '1970-01-03' BETWEEN date_start AND date_finish;
+------+
| t_id |
+------+
|    2 |
+------+
```

What w_id's had no task from 1970-01-01 to 1970-01-10?

```
 SELECT distinct id FROM workers WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT w_id FROM assignments WHERE ( (date_start <= '1970-01-01' AND date_finish IS NULL) OR (date_start <= '1970-01-01' AND date_finish >= '1970-01-01') OR (date_start >= '1970-01-01' AND date_start <= '1970-01-10')));
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
```

+----+

What tasks was w_id(1) doing from 1970-01-03 to 1970-01-12?

```
SELECT t_id FROM assignments WHERE w_id = 1 AND ( (date_start >= 1970-01-03 AND date_finish IS NULL) OR (date_start >= 1970-01-03 AND date_finish <= 1970-01-12));
+------+
| t_id |
+------+
|    2 |
|    3 |
+------+
```

What tasks are currently not assigned to any worker? (LETS assume that today is 1970-02-01)

```
SELECT distinct id FROM tasks WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT t_id FROM assignments WHERE ( (date_start <= '1970-02-01' AND date_finish IS NULL) OR (date_start <= '1970-02-01' AND date_finish >= '1970-02-01') OR (date_start >= '1970-02-01' AND date_start <= '1970-02-01')));
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  1 |
+----+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborate answer. There was no need to also example the queries but I guess that makes it really complete for future references. I'll wait for some more input if there are any other solutions to this, but it seems begin/end colums are the best way to go. Or in other words the answer seems acceptable to me, but if I had any idea if there any downsides/pitfalls or better ways I would have asked in the first place :D

Comment: One query isn't working properly. Maybe update it? :)
`SELECT t_id FROM assignments WHERE w_id = 1 AND date_start = '1970-01-03';` only works if the date_start exactly matches and doesn't tell what w_id(1) was doing on that day. I think this should be:
`SELECT t_id FROM assignments WHERE w_id = 1 AND '1970-01-03' BETWEEN date_start AND date_finish;`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, I fix the answer.